# Error in reading CSV through command line as Numpy 2d Matrix

Tags: python, csv, numpy, genfromtxt

I am trying to read data in CSV file as numpy matrix using **csv.reader()** function to store it into Numpy 2d matrix using the following code:

```
import sys
import csv
filename1 = sys.argv[0]
reader = csv.reader(open(filename1, "rb"), delimiter=",")
x = list(reader)
result = numpy.array(x).astype('int')
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "q1.py", line 94, in <module>
result = numpy.array(x).astype('int') ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I also followed this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy) but then I get different error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q1-prac.py", line 24, in <module>
    result = genfromtxt(filename1, delimiter=',')
  File "/home/ashutosh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1769, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #13 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
    Line #22 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
    Line #36 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
    Line #37 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
    Line #40 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
    Line #46 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
```

Please suggest some solution to this.

Comment: You need to skip the starting line (if you have the header). While reading matrix the array should be of same length. Show 2 to 3 lines of CSV, I can help you better.

Comment: What does the list `x` look like?  Also verify the `filename1`.  Usually `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script, while `argv[1]` is the first argument string.  You may also need to show a us a sample of the `csv` file.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj that was my mistake. sys.argv[0] was the name of file being executed, so there was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because you have initialized the one-dimensional `numpy` array and trying to add 3 columns into a single row. try initializing 3d array and do the same