# read ascii text files into numerical array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

There is a data file shown as follows. Each line has four components. I would like to read whole file as an numerical array(matrix), and each line represents a slice of array.

This is what I do

```
f = open('/data/training.txt'  ,'r')
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    myarray = np.fromstring(line, dtype=float, sep=',')
    print(myarray)
```

But the printed result are like this. What is the right way to read this ascii text file, where each entry is a float point value.

```
[ 0.]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[ 0.]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[ 0.]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[ 0.]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[ 0.]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[ 0.]
```

[image]

Comment: What? I don't understand what you are trying to do here at all. What does your text-file look like? What output are you *expecting*. Please do not post images.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy

Comment: Try changing sep=',' to sep=' ' in your np.fromstring()

Comment: `data = np.genfromtxt(yourfile)` should work, giving a (n,4) float array.