# write rows in pandas dataframe and append it to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the output of my script as year and the count of word from an article in that particular year :

```
abcd
2013
118
2014
23
xyz
2013
1
2014
45
```

I want to have each year added as a new column to my existing dataframe which contains only words.

Expected output:

```
Terms 2013  2014  2015 
abc   118   76    90
xyz   23    0     36
```

The input for my script was a csv file :

```
Terms
xyz
abc
efg
```

The script I wrote is :

```
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', header = None)

for row in df.itertuples():
    term = (str(row[1]))
    u = "http: term=%s&mindate=%d/01/01&maxdate=%d/12/31"
    print(term)
    startYear = 2013
    endYear = 2018  

for year in range(startYear, endYear+1):
    url = u % (term.replace(" ", "+"), year, year)
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    doc = ET.XML(page)
    count = doc.find("Count").text
    print(year)
    print(count)
```

The `df.head` is :

```
                         0
0           1,2,3-triazole
1  16s rrna gene amplicons
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance !!

Comment: `the output of my script`: Is this a `list`, output from `print`, or something else? We need to know what you are starting with to help you reach your destination.

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear. It is the `list` output from `print`

Comment: Nope still not clear. What does `list` output from `print` mean? Think of it this way, what can we copy-paste into our code to replicate the object containing all those items?

Comment: I have edited my question with the script and input format.

Comment: Can you show us `df.head()` instead?

Comment: Update your question, please. No code in comments. No images / links either.

Comment: @jpp edited the question for `df.head`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173558/discussion-between-k-s-and-jpp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

def mkdf(filename):
    def combine(term, l):
        d = {"term": term}
        d.update(dict(zip(l[::2], l[1::2])))
        return d

    term = None
    other = []
    with open(filename) as I:
        n = 0
        for line in I:
            line = line.strip()
            try:
                int(line)
            except Exception as e:
                # not an int
                if term:    # if we have one, create the record
                     yield combine(term, other)

                term = line
                other = []
                n = 0
            else:
                if n > 0:
                    other.append(line)
            n += 1

        # and the last one 
        yield combine(term, other)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pandas as pd
    import sys

    df = pd.DataFrame([r for r in mkdf(sys.argv[1])])
    print(df)
```

usage: python scriptname.py /tmp/IN ( or other file with your data)

Output:

```
  2013 2014  term
0  118   23  abcd
1    1   45   xyz
```

Comment: What should be in `"/tmp/IN"`

Comment: the file with the data you mentioned. I've changed the script to accept the file via commandline.

Answer (score 1):

I would read the csv with numpy in an array, then reshape it also with numpy and then the resulting matrix/2D array to a DataFrame

Comment: Not very familiar with numpy, can you help me with this

Comment: to read the file : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy    and    to reshape, sorry, not resize:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html    and  from array to DataFrame: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: This is more of a comment. If you could add some sample code to solve OP's problem, that would be ideal

Comment: DJK, I do not know how the csv looks like, therfore I cannot actually give the code solution. In my comment though are links to many code examples, for each step. I did not find it fair to copy from other sources, just gave the source.