# Read a .txt file as an array and obtain value of a specified index in Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a big .txt data file with the format like (all numbers):

```
0 1.2 2 3.1
20 21.2 22 23
30 31 32 33.01
```

I want to import the 2nd column, for example, of this matrix into a variable. Here is the code that I have wrote. First, I import all the matrix into a variable as string and convert it into an array, named "data" here. Then, want to access data[1][1] or data[:][1] But, it gives the following error

> IndexError: too many indices for array

Any idea what is the error or what is the efficient way of doing the job? Many thanks

```
import csv
data=[]
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
   for line in f:
      if line.endswith('\n'):
          line=line[:-1] 

      data=np.asarray(line)  
      print(data)
```

Comment: Did Python not tell you at what line this error occurs? Strange – it usually does.

Comment: data[1,1] or data[:,1]

Comment: Why are you creating a `csv.reader` instance and then never using it?

Comment: @usr2564301 Actually, I execute the code and, then, try data[1][1]. But, I could have this at the end of my code, too.

Comment: @bakka data[1,1], data[:,1], data[1][1] all gives error

Comment: @larsks yes, It could be removed. That is because I am new to Python :)

Comment: @YousefVh isnt my answer correct ? :D

Comment: @Fabian It gives a row, not a column!! Either I use array2d[:][0] or array2d[0][:], the first line (not the first column) is obtained!!

Comment: I'm reopening this because the proposed duplicate doesn't address the OP's points of confusion.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the file line by line and saving each in a list is equivalent to making a list of strings:

```
In [98]: txt='''0 1.2 2 3.1
    ...: 20 21.2 22 23
    ...: 30 31 32 33.01'''.splitlines()
In [99]: txt
Out[99]: ['0 1.2 2 3.1', '20 21.2 22 23', '30 31 32 33.01']
```

Making an array from that just produces a 1d array of strings.  That can't be indexed as a 2d numeric array:

```
In [100]: np.array(txt)
Out[100]: array(['0 1.2 2 3.1', '20 21.2 22 23', '30 31 32 33.01'], dtype='<U14')
```

If you first split the lines into substrings:

```
In [101]: [line.split() for line in txt]
Out[101]: 
[['0', '1.2', '2', '3.1'],
 ['20', '21.2', '22', '23'],
 ['30', '31', '32', '33.01']]
In [102]: np.array([line.split() for line in txt], dtype=float)
Out[102]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  1.2 ,  2.  ,  3.1 ],
       [20.  , 21.2 , 22.  , 23.  ],
       [30.  , 31.  , 32.  , 33.01]])
```

This is a 2d array.

We can select a column from that array.  But note that the result is a 1d array:

```
In [104]: np.array([line.split() for line in txt], dtype=float)[:,1]
Out[104]: array([ 1.2, 21.2, 31. ])
```

Don't worry about this being a 'row' or 'column'.  We could change shape to (1,3) or (3,1), but for most `numpy` purposes a 1d shape, (3,) is just as good.

`numpy` has good `csv` loader (two actually):

```
In [105]: np.genfromtxt(txt)
Out[105]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  1.2 ,  2.  ,  3.1 ],
       [20.  , 21.2 , 22.  , 23.  ],
       [30.  , 31.  , 32.  , 33.01]])
```

Usually `genfromtxt` is given a file name, but it works fine anything that feeds it lines, such as the `txt` list.

And if you are interested in just one column, you can specify it with `usecols` (there are many more possible parameters):

```
In [106]: np.genfromtxt(txt, usecols=1)
Out[106]: array([ 1.2, 21.2, 31. ])
```

`genfromtxt` isn't the fastest loader.  It you need more speed we usually recommend the `pandas` loaded. `pandas` has some fancier handling of quotes and missing values, but you don't seem to need that here.  `numpy` users don't seem to use the `csv` module much; it may be it just isn't needed.

---

If you really must have a `column vector`, here's how to use `reshape`:

```
In [110]: col1 = np.genfromtxt(txt, usecols=1)
In [111]: col1
Out[111]: array([ 1.2, 21.2, 31. ])
In [112]: col1.reshape(3,1)
Out[112]: 
array([[ 1.2],
       [21.2],
       [31. ]])
```

---

Let's build the array line by line:

```
In [116]: data = []
In [117]: for line in txt:
     ...:     arr = np.array(line.split(), dtype=float)
     ...:     print(arr.shape)
     ...:     data.append(arr)
     ...:     print(data)
     ...:     
     ...:     
(4,)
[array([0. , 1.2, 2. , 3.1])]
(4,)
[array([0. , 1.2, 2. , 3.1]), array([20. , 21.2, 22. , 23. ])]
(4,)
[array([0. , 1.2, 2. , 3.1]), array([20. , 21.2, 22. , 23. ]), array([30.  , 31.  , 32.  , 33.01])]
```

`data` is now a list of arrays:

```
In [118]: data
Out[118]: 
[array([0. , 1.2, 2. , 3.1]),
 array([20. , 21.2, 22. , 23. ]),
 array([30.  , 31.  , 32.  , 33.01])]
```

Join those arrays into one array:

```
In [119]: np.array(data)
Out[119]: 
array([[ 0.  ,  1.2 ,  2.  ,  3.1 ],
       [20.  , 21.2 , 22.  , 23.  ],
       [30.  , 31.  , 32.  , 33.01]])
```

(Check the shape after doing this.  If the individual arrays differ in shape, the result will not be a 2d array; it will be a 1d array of arrays, which is closer to the original list of arrays.)

Comment: Great explanation. thanks. I fully understood what is going on. But, There is one thing that is not clear to me and it is in the above code of mine that when I do print(data) I see the content of the .txt file. But, when I try even data[0] or data[0][0], it gives error, while I have used the "np.asarray" command to convert list into array.

Comment: `data = np.array(line)` assigns the array object to the `data` variable, replacing the `[]` list you initially assigned to it, and replacing any previous line assignment.  To collect objects in a list, you need to `data.append(line)`.  You may need to practice with some simple list construction loops.

Comment: I edited my answer to illustrate building the array line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Classic way would be like:

```
with open('test.txt') as txt:
    array2d = [[float(digit) for digit in line.split()] for line in txt]

print(array2d[:][0])
```

Reference: [List Comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

I think performance wise numpy should be faster :/

> **Update:**

For numpy you could use the `loadtxt` function.

```
import numpy as np
textfile = np.loadtxt("test.txt")
print(textfile[0][0])
```

Reference: [Reading and Writing Data Files](https://www.python-course.eu/numpy_reading_writing.php)

> **Update2:**  IndexError: too many indices for array

```
import csv 
import numpy as np #missing
data = [] #create a empty array
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f: #opens the textfile in readmode and stores in f
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True) #creating a reader instance but never used
    for line in f: #loop for each line in file
            if line.endswith('\n'): #if the file ends with a new line
                line = line[:-1] #set to last line

            data = np.asarray(line) # here is one bigger mistake you overwrite the data array with just one line
            print(data) #print out this one line
```

So you only get the last line stored in your data array.

Note: There is no way to determine the lenght of a line, so you have to read in the file. You cant jump to this specific line, there some ways to improve the performance so please let us know how big your file is or what the expected speed looks like.

> **Update3:** Get the Column

```
import numpy as np
textfile = np.loadtxt("test.txt")
print(textfile[:,0])
```

Reference: [Numpy Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I wonder what is the problem with the way I did? and secondly, since, I need only the 2nd column, for example, I want to save only that column which I think can be the efficient way. However, this way or what I have done at the top in my code, imports all the .txt data and saves them in a variable. While, other columns, that are saved, too, are useless.

Comment: @YousefVh i think the second update is more specific on your code ?

Comment: yes, the second update works, too. However, this solution also does not gives value of a column, but gives values of a row!! In my code, the line        data=np.asarray(line)  seems to be correct because print(data)  shows all the contents of the .txt file not one line.