# Import CSV file in python to a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I'm trying to import some values from a csv-file to a numpy array in python. 
So far I've read the CSV-file with pandas but I can't succeed with creating a numpy array with the values from the csv columns.

Comment: Do you have some code? What have you tried? Have you searched? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3519314/4146962

Comment: Dataframe `.values` or `to_numpy()` is the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer. Just had to use DataFrame.values

Comment: `.values` not `.values()`..  It's a property that returns an array, not a method.