# Reading from text file and storing in array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

If I have a text file containing the following numbers:

```
5.078780 5.078993
7.633073 7.633180
2.919274 2.919369
3.410284 3.410314
```

How can read it and store it in an array, so that it becomes:

```
[[5.078780,5.078993],[7.633073,7.633180],[2.919274,2.919369],[3.410284,3.410314]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any idea about relevant functions to use etc.? Try breaking the problem down into two parts: reading the data from a file and formatting the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    output = [ line.strip().split(' ') for line in file.readlines()]

# Cast strings to floats
output = [[float(j) for j in i] for i in output]    
print(output)
```

should give the desired output:

```
[[5.07878, 5.078993], [7.633073, 7.63318], [2.919274, 2.919369], [3.410284, 3.410314]]
```

Comment: This is the right answer :)

Comment: Can use`map` to improve readablity

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
with open('filepath') as f:
    array = [line.split() for line in f.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach:
Have a result list = `[]`
Split the text by newlines `\n`.
Now in a for-loop
   split each line by a space char  and assign to a tuple
   append tuple to the result list
I'm refraining from writing code here to let you work it out.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
with open ("data.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()

for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i]=data[i].split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python provides the perfect module for this, it's called [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```py
import csv

def csv_to_array(file_name, **kwargs):
    with open(file_name) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, **kwargs)
        return [list(map(float, row)) for row in reader]


print(csv_to_array('test.csv'))
```

If you later have a file with a different field separator, say ";", then you'll just have to change the call to:

```py
print(csv_to_array('test.csv', delimiter=';'))
```

Note that if you don't care about importing `numpy` then [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3519314/1720199) is even better.

Answer (score 0):

You first want to retrieve the file content in an array of string (each string is one line of the file)

with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.readlines()

*Refer to open doc for more: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open_)*

Then you want to create a list

```
content_list = []
```

And then you want to fill it with each string, when each string should be split with a space(using `split()` function) which make a list with the two values and add it to `content_list`, use a for loop !

```
for line in file_content:
    values = line.split(' ') # split the line at the space
    content_list.append(values)
```

By the way, this can be simplified with a *List Comprehension*:

```
content_list = [s.split(' ') for s in file_content]
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert to this exact format :

```
with open('filepath', 'r') as f:
    raw = f.read()

arr = [[float(j) for j in i.split(' ')] for i in raw.splitlines()]
print arr
```

outputs :

```
[[5.07878, 5.078993], [7.633073, 7.63318], [2.919274, 2.919369], [3.410284, 3.410314]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('blah.txt', 'r') as file:
    a=[[l.split(' ')[0], l.split(' ')[1] for l in file.readlines() ]
```

Comment: You can simply reduce the `split` calls from 2 to 1 by splitting on `l`