# How to import data from excel into python array?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I have a very basic neural network. For the array data, what code do I need to do to point the array to data in an excel file?

Here is the code with the data hard coded.

How do I tell the array to look at another file on the computer?

```
import numpy as np

# X = (hours studying, hours sleeping), y = score on test
xAll = np.array(([2, 9], [1, 5], [3, 6], [5, 10], [8,8], [1,4]), 
dtype=float) # input data
y = np.array(([92], [60], [89], [91], [99]), dtype=float) # output

# scale units
xAll = xAll/np.amax(xAll, axis=0) # scaling input data
y = y/100 # scaling output data (max test score is 100)

# split data
X = np.split(xAll, [5])[0] # training data has to match all input data E 
X testing data
xPredicted = np.split(xAll, [5])[1] # testing data

class Neural_Network(object):
  def __init__(self):
  #parameters
    self.inputSize = 2
    self.outputSize = 1
    self.hiddenSize = 3
```

Comment: Pandas has built in support for writing and reading excel files. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-excel-reader

Comment: Maybe take a look at this solved question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy

Answer (score 5):

I recommand considering using Pandas.

with pandas you can easily read excel files on your computer and upload it.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(path_to_your_file)
```

take a look here for more: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

and here too https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the third-party library [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), which is provided with all kinds of read/write functions for plain-text and binary files.

In your case, I would import the data straight with the [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function:

```python
import pandas as pd

data = pandas.read_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is probably best for this but you could try saving the excel doc as a csv file if you wanted to use the standard library.

```
import csv

csvfile = 'C://path//to//csvfile.csv'

with open(csvfile) as f:
    data = list(list(d) for d in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
```

Comment: Thanks Zak! Sorry for such a silly beginner question... but now how do I get the data into the array above instead of hard coding the numbers like I have been?