# How to convert list of strings to floats?

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I am importing numbers from a csv file that looks like the picture attached:
[CSV File View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYR3s.png)

However, those numbers are imported as a string and not a float so I need to convert. I've tried using this method but it just says it cannot convert.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('20191031-0002_09.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    y = [columns[1] for columns in reader]
```

From research on stack I found this which I thought might work:

```
numbers = []
for x in y:
      numbers.extend([n for n in map(float, line.split(' '))])
```

However, my array still comes out as a list of strings like this:

```
['1.09805600', '1.09805600']
```

Whereas, I want it to be a array of floats.

Hope you can help.

Comment: `line.split()` where `line` is declare???

Comment: Since it appears you're trying to do something with Numpy, try using `np.genfromtxt` to read the CSV file instead, as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy Alternatively, use Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite confusing, as pointed out above you have not declared `line` anywhere, but if you want to convert the string `'1.09805600'` to a float, simply call it a float.

```
>>> x = '1.09805600'
>>> float(x)
1.09805600
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('20191031-0002_09.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    y = [columns[1] for columns in reader]
    print (y)
numbers = []
numbers.extend([n for n in map(float,y)])
print (numbers)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/@FrustetedD/GenerousPurpleAlgorithm)

**if it's not work then please add your sample `csv` file in given demo link**

Comment: Hi @FrustratedDeveloper it didn't work but Ive added my csv to the demo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert *both* columns to float so that you end up with a list that looks like:

```
[
    [0, 1.098056],
    [.000002, 1.098056],
    etc.
]
```

Then this will do it:

```
import csv

with open('20191031-0002_09.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    rows = [[float(columns[0]), float(columns[1])] for columns in reader]
```

If you just care about the second column:

```
    y = [float(columns[1]) for columns in reader]
```

**Edited to handle columns with bad values:**

```
import csv, sys

with open('20191031-0002_09.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    y = []
    for columns in reader:
        try:
            y.append(float(columns[1]))
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Unable to convert '{columns[1]}'", file=sys.stderr)
            # uncomment out the next line if you want to substitute 0.0
            # y.append(0.0)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but it still says: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'âˆž'

Comment: @BenWatson Then you have in one of the columns something that is not a valid string that can be converted. What would like to do with a value such as `'âˆž'`? Bypass it altogether? Use a value of 0? By the way, was this in the first column or are you really only interested in converting the second column. There is a fix for everything.