# How to make a csv file into numpy array format?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to load the iris dataset using panda.

I did the fllowing:

```
import pandas as pd
iris= pd.read_csv("data_path/iris.csv")
```

However this is not in matrix form and I cannot access elements like `iris[0][2]`.

I'm wondering how to transform the the csv file into a say numpy array?

Comment: Pandas reads data into it's own dataframe structure, but you can basically think of it as a dictionary, where column names are keys and values in said columns are, well... Values in an array. So, instead of converting it into a numpy 2D array you should consider using pandas's vast abilities to work with data and use Iris["column_name"][index] to get what you need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read CSV data into a record array in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy)

Comment: I know for a fact there is plenty of information available which could help with this. What is particular about this question which isn't covered by those existing resources? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on converting your dataframe into a numpy array, you can use iris.to_numpy() to get what you need, since pandas is built on top of numpy and they are tightly integrated. However, as I explained in my comment, you should consider investing some time into learning pandas, it is an incredibly powerful tool.

Answer (score -2):

There are two options to access the data:

First, use the pandas dataframe. To access rows, columns, or elements in a dataframe you can use **.loc** or **.iloc**.

```
import pandas as pd
iris= pd.read_csv("data_path/iris.csv")
iris.iloc[0,2]
```

You can learn more about it in this post:

[PythonHow.com: Accessing Dataframe Columns Rows and Cells](https://pythonhow.com/accessing-dataframe-columns-rows-and-cells/)

Second, read the file using NumPy **genfromtext** function

```
import numpy as np
iris = np.genfromtxt("data_path/iris.csv")
```

Read this post to learn more:

[RIP Tutorial: Reading CSV Files](https://riptutorial.com/numpy/example/22990/reading-csv-files)

Comment: This is effectively a link-only answer.