# Python List Slicing from CSV

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to parse the following file:

```
student_id, 521, 597, 624, 100,
1, 99, 73, 97, 98,
2, 98, 71, 70, 99,
```

I have the following code:

```
def load_students(filename):
    exercises = []
    students = []
    grades = []
    fr = None
    try:
        fr = open(filename, 'r')
        for line in fr:
            tokens = line.strip('\n').split(',')

            # Get Exercises
            # Need help here

            # Get Students
            if tokens[0].isdigit():
                students.append(tokens[0])

            # Get grades
            grades.append([int(x) for x in tokens[1:]])
    except IOError:
        print("IO Error!")

    finally:
        if fr is not None:
            fr.close()
            print(exercises)
            print(students)
            print(grades)
        return np.array(exercises), np.array(students), np.array(grades)
```

How I can get the file header (521,597,624, 100) as an array excluding the `student_id` string?

Comment: Since you are already using Numpy, did you try just [using Numpy functionality to read the CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy)?

Comment: Whatever wrote that file was not CSV conformant. It should not have spaces after the commas. Those may be treated as valid column values by CSV parsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
def load_students(filename):
    exercises = []
    students = []
    grades = []
    fr = None
    try:
        fr = open(filename, 'r')
        for line in fr:
            tokens = [val.strip() for val in line.strip('\n').split(',') if val.strip()]

            # Get Exercises
            if tokens[0].isdigit() == False:
                exercises+=[int(x) for x in tokens[1:]]

            # Get Students
            if tokens[0].isdigit():
                students.append(tokens[0])

            # Get grades
            if tokens[0].isdigit():
                grades.append([int(x) for x in tokens[1:]])
    except IOError:
        print("IO Error!")

    finally:
        if fr is not None:
            fr.close()
            print(exercises)
            print(students)
            print(grades)


load_students("data.csv")
```

Output:

```
[521, 597, 624, 100]
['1', '2']
[[99, 73, 97, 98], [98, 71, 70, 99]]
```

Explanation:

I have stripped the white spaces in `[val.strip() for val in line.strip('\n').split(',') if val.strip()]`.

Also I used the same logic you have included to identify the first line elements as exercise numbers (first character is not numeric).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of slotting in to your existing code, you could add an `else` clause to your `if tokens[0].isdigit()`:

```
    for line in fr:
        tokens = line.strip('\n').split(',')

        if tokens[0].isdigit():
            # Get Students
            students.append(tokens[0])
            # Get grades
            grades.append([int(x) for x in tokens[1:] if x.strip().isdigit()])
        else:
            exercises = [int(x) for x in tokens[1:] if x.strip().isdigit()]
```

If you don't need the `exercises` values to be integers, just use

```
exercises = tokens[1:]
```

Also, if there might be other random data in the file, you could make the `else` be

```
elif tokens[0] == 'student_id'
```

Comment: But I need all of them, `students`, `grades`, and `exercises`. the `exercises` are the IDS on the header only, while `grades` are from the second line.

Comment: @TheUnreal that's what this will do; if the first entry on the line is a digit it will grab the student and grades, otherwise (presumably first line only) it will grab the exercises

Comment: Thanks, not sure why but the grades are missing the last character of the last element (showing `9` instead of `98`

Comment: @TheUnreal that is weird; if I just process a string line as `'1, 99, 73, 97, 98, '` it gets the expected result of `[[99, 73, 97, 98]]`. Note I have changed the answer slightly to deal with the trailing `, ` in the line. See https://rextester.com/EPRB39947

Comment: Not sure why it's not working from the CSV, `[[99 73 97  9]
 [98 71 70  9]]`

Comment: Can you verify what's in`line`?

Comment: It's weird that the answer you've accepted works - it's essentially exactly the same code. Anyway, I'm glad you've got a working solution so let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```py
import pandas as pd
def load_students(filename):
    df= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    df.drop(columns = df.columns[-1], inplace=True)
    df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns]
    exercises = df.columns[1:].to_numpy()
    students = df.student_id.to_numpy()
    grades = df.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy()
    return exercises, students, grades
    
print(load_students('data.csv'))
```

Output:

```
(array(['521', '597', '624', '100'], dtype=object), array([1, 2]), array([[99, 73, 97, 98],
       [98, 71, 70, 99]]))
```

Comment: Very close, I just don't need the `student_id` as part of the headers.

Comment: Not sure why but the exercises array is missing the `100` (shows only 521 597 624)

Comment: @TheUnreal Please check the csv at your end.

Answer (score 0):

To process `csv`-files in python I would highly recommend to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Here is an examlpe:
Your file (slightly modificated, removed spaces in the header and commas at the end of the lines):

```
student_id,521,597,624,100
1, 99, 73, 97, 98
2, 98, 71, 70, 99
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0) # student_id becomes an index now
df.keys()
```

`df.keys()` returns a list of the header and will give you the desired result. You also can do other things much simpler:`df['521'].values` will give you a numpy array with the values of that column for example.

Comment: Or perhaps `pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)` so that student_id becomes an index.

Comment: And it would be good to mention why you had to remove spaces from the csv.