# CSV package in python loads only first 34739332 rows and not beyond that?

Tags: python, csv

I am working on a file with *156371992* rows and using the *CSV* package of python. But it always loads only the first *34739332*. It is not throwing any error which I suppose is because the reader is believing to have reached the end of the file which is far from it. I couldn't find anything docs, am adding the code snippet too

```py
has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
csvfile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
if has_header:
    next(reader)
print("len of reader", len(list(reader)))
```

Which always gives *34739332* as value. Any explanations?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Check your file closely. Is there a line with a wrong number of commas? Try to debug by printing `list(reader)[-1]` to see what it has as the last line. Also, do you really have a CSV file with 156 million rows in it? if so, maybe it's time to switch to a proper database

Comment: `has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))` it seems you are limiting by `read(1024)`. Can you try with big number like `has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024*2))`?

Comment: I think the problem is memory. You should not load all the data at once. iteration will help.

Comment: @r.b.leon might have a point. 34739332 is suspiciously close to `2 ** 25`, so it might be Python / your OS limitation on your environment, although I would have expected to see a `MemoryError` being raised if that was the case.

Comment: If this is Windows, make sure the file doesn't have a Ctrl-Z in it.

Comment: @DeepSpace, I had checked the rows near 34739332 manually, there was no error. I had loaded the data via iteration too via for loop but results were similar. I think your opinions are right regarding it as a memory issue. But I too expected to see a memory error. Will try on different spec computer then

Comment: @MarkRansom I am running ubuntu though

Comment: @DeepSpace To let you know, there was one corrupt line in the file at that point as you said, when checked manually, the open office removed the corrupted line so didn't discover it. But the irony is that none of the packages threw an error or skipped to the next line,.

Answer (score -3):

For datasets, It might be better to import `read_csv` from `pandas` rather than use the csv library. Try

```
from pandas import read_csv
dataset = read_csv(csvfile)
```

This will create a pandas [Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). If you need to manipulate it, the pandas library functions should be adequate. If not, you can import `numpy` and use `dataset = numpy.array(dataset)`.

If that doesn't work, try importing NumPy [and using `genfromtxt` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3519314/14500434).