# How to remove quotation from a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, file, 2d, quotation-marks

there. I'm trying to remove quotations marks the following output

```
[['40' '40']
 ['10' '10']
 ['200' '200']
 ['230' '231']
 ['40' '43 ']
 ['15' '45 ']
 ['220' '190']]
```

I desire the following output:

```
[[40 40]
 [10 10]
 [....]]
```

here are my codes. I've been trying for a while but was unable to figure it out. If anyone can help, it will be highly appreciative.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def extract_file(file_name):
    file = open(file_name,'r')
    lines = ([line.strip("\n").split(",") for line in file])
    x= np.array(lines)
    return x
t= extract_file("backyard.txt")
```

Comment: The quotes aren't in the data, they're shown because the array elements are strings. Convert them to numbers when creating the array.

Comment: @Barmar No, the elements are integers, but when turned them into 2d array, the elements was turned into strings as well

Comment: No they aren't. `line.strip("\n").split(",")` returns a list of strings, not integers.

Comment: No, you need to call `int()` on the elements after splitting. See my answer.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy for reading a CSV directly into a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

`@Barmar` comments , `np.genfromtxt` could be use

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def extract_file():
    return np.genfromtxt('test.txt',delimiter=',')
print(extract_file())
```

Output:

```
[[ 40.  40.]
 [ 10.  10.]
 [200. 200.]
 [230. 231.]
 [ 40.  43.]
 [ 15.  45.]
 [220. 190.]]
```

Its , Float , but i think it will works the same,

```
>>>type(numpy.genfromtxt('test.txt',delimiter=',')[0][0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: If I were to input the file as file = open("backyard.txt", "r") i get an error saying that     lines.append(int(line))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','

Answer (score 0):

`line.strip("\n").split(",")` returns a list of strings, so you're creating an array of strings, not integers. Convert them to integers before creating the array.

```
lines = [list(map(int, line.strip("\n").split(","))) for line in file]
```

Comment: I tried that although there is an error: IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed.

Comment: Try with the call to `list()` added.