# How to load a txt file into 2d matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, txt

I am fairly need to Python and need some help. I am trying to load a txt file and store it as a variable, N where N is supposed to be a square matrix. However, when I tried to check, the ndim() of N is 1 and the number of columns is not equal the number of rows.

I tried the following codes:

```
N = open('Graph2021.txt', 'r').readlines()
N = np.array(M)
```

Could someone please help. I have attached a screenshot of part of the txt file to show the breakage of the code to separate the columns (I think).

txt file is filled with zeros and ones:

[image: txt file]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read CSV data into a record array in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

N_lines = open('Graph2021.txt', 'r').readlines()
N_matrixlist = [list(map(float,i.strip().split(','))) for i in N_lines]
N = np.array(N_matrixlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading a file as a list with each element to be a line. However by what you described each line has `N` element. And surely it must be separated by something (A white space, comma, etc). You have to split your each line by that separator.

```
with open('Graph2021.txt', 'r') as the_file:
    M = []
    for each_line in the_file:
        M.append(each_line.split(",")) # , is separator...
    N = np.array(M)
```

More pythonic way:

```
with open('Graph2021.txt', 'r') as the_file:
    N = np.array([each_line.split(",") for each_line in the_file]) # , is separator...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! It works but it seems that the answer from @Suneesh Jacob is slightly better as I am able to check if there is any NaN values using np.isnan(matrix).any() as he converted it to float

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use context manager (the `with` part). But yes @ Suneesh Jacob  gave a good answer.