# Extracting Columns from .dat using np.loadtxt Python

Tags: python, text-files

I have this text file: www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/~plewis/geogg122/python/delnorte.dat

I want to extract column 3 and 4.

I am using np.loadtxt - getting the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2000-01-01
```

I am only interested in the year 2005. How can I extracted both columns?

Comment: `numpy.loadtxt('delnorte.dat', usecols=[2, 3], dtype=object)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a custom conversion function for a specific column to `loadtxt`.
Since you are only interested in the year I use a `lambda`-function to split the date on `-` and to convert the first part to an `int`:

```
data = np.loadtxt('delnorte.dat',
         usecols=(2,3),
         converters={2: lambda s: int(s.split('-')[0])},
         skiprows=27)

array([[ 2000.,   190.],
       [ 2000.,   170.],
       [ 2000.,   160.],
       ..., 
       [ 2010.,   185.],
       [ 2010.,   175.],
       [ 2010.,   165.]])
```

To filter then for the year `2005` you can use [logical indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) in numpy:

```
data_2005 = data[data[:,0] == 2005]

array([[ 2005.,   210.],
       [ 2005.,   190.],
       [ 2005.,   190.],
       [ 2005.,   200.],
        ....])
```

Comment: This is great- How should I extract the year (i.e. 2005) and its corresponding value from the array I just created? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use NumPy.loadtxt to read these values, you should rather use the [`csv` module](http://pastebin.com/JyVC4XfF) to load the file and read its data.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using the csv module.  I adapted this answer: [reading csv files in scipy/numpy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859404/reading-csv-files-in-scipy-numpy-in-python)
to apply to your question. Not sure if you desire the data in a numpy array or if a list is sufficient.

```
import numpy as np
import urllib2
import csv

txtFile = csv.reader(open("delnorte.dat.txt", "r"), delimiter='\t')

fields = 5                   
records = [] 
for row, record in enumerate(txtFile):
    if (len(record) != fields or record[0]=='#'):
        pass
        # print "Skipping malformed record or comment: {}, contains {} fields ({} expected)".format(record,len(record),fields)
    else:
        if record[2][0:4] == '2005': 
            # assuming you want columns 3 & 4 with the first column indexed as 0
            records.append([int(record[:][3]), record[:][4]] ) 

# if desired slice the list of lists to put a single column into a numpy array
npData = np.asarray([ npD[0] for npD in records] )
```